# How To Remove "Publicly Recommend On Google" PopUp From Google PlusOne Buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button, css

How do I stop Google's "popup message" that shows up upon hovering over [the Google PlusOne button?](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/)

I don't want to give Google ***that*** much recognition on my web page.

Comment: I don't believe you legally can - I THINK it says in their TOS that if you want to use their button, you have to use it as they provide and editing it is a violation of those TOS.

Comment: `<opinion rant="true" devilsAdvocate="true">` Ditch the button.  Google has been using its muscle lately to impose some alarming changes on its users. If google insists on bullying like this, stand up to them by not including their button. `</opinion>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html

Emphasis added

> Publishers **may not alter or obfuscate a Google+ Button**, and Publishers
>   may not associate a Google+ Button with advertising content, such as
>   putting the Google+ Button on or adjacent to an ad, or placing ads in
>   shared content, unless authorized to do so by Google. Publishers also
>   may not place in shared content any text, image, or other content that
>   violates the Google+ User Content and Conduct Policy.
>
> For buttons that may be rendered by the Publisher, such as the Sharing
>   Link, **the Publisher must use only the official Google-provided icon or
>   a plain text and link combination**. In either case Publishers must not
>   mislead users as to the purpose of the link.

Comment: Alright... well then, I guess I will be using this answer for the time being: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/embed-google-1-button-without-use-of-javascript-or-iframes

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above all you need to do is to add in your css

```
.gc-reset,.pls-dropBottom{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Works for me.